# How to show something above Twitter bootstrap modal fade?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Probably this is a silly question but I need to show some DIV above Twitter bootstrap modal fade.

The problem is that the DIV is already on the page before the modal fade appears and when it appears it sets itself after all alements on the page shadowing them in spite of any z-index value.

Comment: Code sample is required. At least show what you have done so far...

Comment: Thank you, Hiren, I found a solution

Answer (score 3):

Eventually I got it. Adding **position: absolute** worked for me:

```
<div style="z-index: 1050; position: absolute;">ABOVE THE MODAL FADE</div>
```